how to customize progress indicator in flutter
Please I need a package or code sample on how to achieve this progress indicator as shown in the last image. It's a figma design that I need to replicate in the flutter app. The packages that I got didn't really give me what I want. I just need a way to achieve the progress indicator as shown in the image

You can try something like this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SliderScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SliderScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text('Headache'),
              GradientSlider(
                currentValue: 2,
              ),
              Text('Fever'),
              GradientSlider(
                currentValue: 3.5,
              ),
              Text('Pains'),
              GradientSlider(
                currentValue: 5.5,
              ),
              Text('Energy Levels'),
              GradientSlider(
                currentValue: 9,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GradientSlider extends StatefulWidget {
  final double currentValue;

  const GradientSlider({super.key, required this.currentValue});

  @override
  State<GradientSlider> createState() => _GradientSliderState();
}

class _GradientSliderState extends State<GradientSlider> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        SliderTheme(
          data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
            trackHeight: 8.0,
            activeTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
            inactiveTrackColor: Colors.transparent,
            thumbShape: const RoundSliderThumbShape(enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
            overlayShape: const RoundSliderOverlayShape(overlayRadius: 24.0),
            trackShape: GradientSliderTrackShape(
              gradient: const LinearGradient(
                colors: [Colors.red, Colors.yellow, Colors.green],
                stops: [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: Slider(
            value: widget.currentValue,
            min: 0.0,
            max: 10.0,
            onChanged: (double value) {},
          ),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: List.generate(11, (index) {
            return Text(
              '$index',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 14.0,
                color: Colors.black, // Customize color as needed
              ),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class GradientSliderTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape {
  final LinearGradient gradient;

  GradientSliderTrackShape({required this.gradient});

  @override
  Rect getPreferredRect({
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    Offset offset = Offset.zero,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    bool? isEnabled,
    bool? isDiscrete,
  }) {
    final double trackHeight = sliderTheme.trackHeight ?? 2.0;
    final double trackLeft = offset.dx;
    final double trackTop = offset.dy + (parentBox.size.height - trackHeight) / 2;
    final double trackRight = trackLeft + parentBox.size.width;
    final double trackBottom = trackTop + trackHeight;
    return Rect.fromLTRB(trackLeft, trackTop, trackRight, trackBottom);
  }

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required Offset thumbCenter,
    Offset? secondaryOffset,
    bool? isEnabled,
    bool? isDiscrete,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
  }) {
    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
      parentBox: parentBox,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
    );

    final Paint paint = Paint()
      ..shader = gradient.createShader(trackRect)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(trackRect, const Radius.circular(4.0)),
      paint,
    );
  }
}

The output is:

